# Magento - Add 'Customer Account Navigation' to custom module page

Tags: magento, module

I have a custom module in my magento store. It is currently using the default 2 column layout with magento's left nav as the lefthand sidebar.

How can i go about having the customer account navigation in my left sidebar instead? My current xml file for my module is:

earnings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <earnings_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="earnings/earnings" name="earnings" />
        </reference>
    </earnings_index_index>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1):

solved with:

```
<earnings_index_index translate="label">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="core/template" name="earnings" template="earnings/earnings.phtml" />
    </reference>
</earnings_index_index>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are the snippet on adding link to left navigation in my account section.

```
<customer_account translate="label">        
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label"><name>nameoflink</name><path>path/index/index/</path><label>Custom Account Link</label></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: does this go in my existing module's earnings.xml or in my local.xml?

Comment: it totally depends on your choice in both the xml it should work.

Comment: Sorry i just checked the code over, I don't want to add a link to the navigation, i want to add the navigation to a page

Comment: i haven't understand your question please elaborate.